# Doctrine joined inheritance combined with single table inheritance

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I want to have the following situation in my model

I have different concrete vehicle types in my space, like a `bicycle` a `motorcycle`, a `car` and a `truck`

Since querying data from a mapped superclass isn't possible, it is not used for my situation.
So to be able to query over all vehicles, i decided to declare `vehicle` as the most top entity and created a entity with `JOINED` inheritance type. Furthermore i must be able to query over more detailed type later. So I group them together in the groups `TwoWheeler` (motorcyle & bicycle) and `FourWheeler` (car and truck)

```
* @ORM\Entity()
* @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"two_wheeler" = "TwoWheeler", "four_wheeler" = "FourWheeler"})
* @ORM\Table(name="vehicle")

abstract class Vehicle 
{
    protected $id;
    ...
}
```

The TwoWheeler should be placed in one table and the FourWheeler in another table. For this i create the two models with SINGLE_TABLE behaviour.

```
* @ORM\Entity()
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"bicycle" = "Bicycle", "motorcycle" = "Motorcycle"})
* @ORM\Table(name="two_wheeler")

abstract class TwoWheeler extends Vehicle
{

}
```

And the same for the four wheeler

```
* @ORM\Entity()
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"car" = "Car", "truck" = "Truck"})
* @ORM\Table(name="four_wheeler")

abstract class FourWheeler extends Vehicle
{

}
```

And last the concrete entites

Car

```
* @ORM\Entity()
abstract class Car extends FourWheeler
{
   ...
}
```

Bicycle

```
* @ORM\Entity()
abstract class Bicycle extends TwoWheeler
{
   ...
}
```

and so on ...

**Problem:**

Doctrine won't create this masterpiece of inheritance ... i think it has problems with a `SINGLE_TABLE` extending a model that is of type `JOINED`

If i let `doctrine migrations` or `doctrine schema` to generate, the `vehicle` table will be created but not the `two_wheeler` and `four_wheeler` one.

I expect a vehicle table summing up at least all vehicles id (and common properties) and a `four_wheeler` and a `two_wheeler` table with specific properties.

There was a similar post 10 months ago

[Doctrine: SINGLE_TABLE inheritance extends from JOINED inheritance is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402664/doctrine-single-table-inheritance-extends-from-joined-inheritance-is-that-possi)

But nobody answered

What is the problem? How can i solve this? Is there a cleaner solution?

Thanks

Comment: isn't the annotation `@InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")`? according to https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance and you miss the `/**` and `*/`

Comment: Let's ignore most specific classes (`Car`, `Truck`, `Bicycle` and `Motorcycle`) for a moment and make `TwoWheeler` and `ForWheeler` non-abstract. Does `doctrine` create the tables now?

Comment: @Edwin yes you re right ... that was a typo, sorry. I edited my post.

Comment: @JovanPerovic Nope, thats still the same result. If i manually add the tables, doctrine want to drop it.

Comment: I suggest not using inheritance here but to use traits for shared elements, like explained e.g. here: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-traits-doctrine-entities/ Avoid too much fancyness in entity inheritance, it will only cause trouble.

Comment: @LBA its not just about having shared properties and methods over multiple classes, that would be indeed easy by using traits ... but for example for using sonata admin you could easily set a parent class (FourWheeler) for an admin and manage their sublclasses (Car, Truck) in one admin instance ... there is no easy way to achieve this by injecting two extra types of entites ... another example: If i just want to have the id's of all vehicles in the database, i have to query n repositories and merge them together ... too complicated in my eyes :/

Comment: then only use a single joined inheritance and create your own distinct column(s) by setting the class name (or any other identifier) to be able to query your stuff. believe me we did all sorts of inheritance and even some combinations but at some point Doctrine gave up (which is totally OK)

Comment: Hmm okay, if this is really the only solution to not be able to mix up both types, ill go for it and consider what kind (single_table, joined) is the lesser evil